# Which calling methods are called for the app-info of the particular app in android?

Tags: android, android-settings

When we long press any application we can get the options like app-info, uninstall, open etc.. so when user choose the app-info option then can we get the info of those calls or methods(the calls which are responsible for that action?) can we see that info of those methods calls in the logs.

I am trying to see that info in the logcat but I didn't find any relevant info. so is it possible to see those methods info in logcat or not?

Please suggest me.

Comment: "can we get the which calls or methods are calling" - can you rephrase it? I dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: @Yegorf  i updated my question. can you see once again?

Comment: Do you want to catch this event in your app or just see it in general system logs?

Comment: @Yegorf       normal system logs. I want to see which methods calls are calling when user clicked on that app info of any application.